# Odd and even cycles of Kneser Graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Show that Kneser Graph $KG_{n,k}$ has no odd cycles of lenght shorter than $1+2\lceil \dfrac{k}{n-2k}\rceil $. What about even cycles?

This is from Matoušek's book. I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If $n\geq3k$ then $1+2\lceil\frac k{n-2k}\rceil\leq 1+2=3$, so the statement is obviously true.

For $n\leq 2k$ there are no cycles at all, so we may restrict ourselves to $n=2k+t$ where $0<t<k$.

Assume $v_1,\ldots,v_{2m+1}$ is an odd cycle.
The $k$ elements of $v_2$ must be completely different from those of $v_1$ and $v_3$ has at least $k-t$ elements from $v_1$
(and at most $t$ of the elements that have not been used yet).
Therefore $v_3$ cannot be adjacent to $v_1$.

Continuing around the cycle we see that $v_5$ has at least $k-2t$ elements from $v_1$,
$v_7$ has at least $k-3t$ element from $v_1$, etc.

In general $v_{2m+1}$ still has at least $k-mt$ elements from $v_1$ and $v_{2m+1}$ can only be
adjacent to $v_1$ if it has no elements from $v_1$.

Therefore the smallest $m$ allowing $v_{2m+1}$ to be adjacent to $v_1$ requires $k-mt\leq 0$ or $m\geq\frac kt=\frac k{n-2k}$.
Since $m$ is an integer this can be written as $m\geq\lceil\frac k{n-2k}\rceil$.
The cycle length in this case is $2m+1$, so the shortest odd cycle has length at least $2\lceil\frac k{n-2k}\rceil+1$.

The even case is easier, and you should be able to do it by yourself now (HINT: exhibit a 4-cycle or a 6-cycle).